# Intrinsic Characterization of when an orbifold (or more general stack) is effective?

Tags: orbifolds, dg.differential-geometry, stacks, lie-groupoids

Recall that an orbifold is an etale and proper differentiable stack $X$. Etale means that it admits an etale atlas $M \to X$ from a manifold $M$ (which is to say it is represented by an etale Lie groupoid $G$ with $M$ as its space of objects, and here etale means that the source map is a local diffeomorphism). At least in the smooth setting, this is also equivalent to the more intrinsic characterization that the automorphism groups of each point of the stack $X$ are all discrete (and that X is a differentiable stack, i.e. has SOME atlas). Proper means that the the diagnoal map $X \to X \times X$ is proper, which is a nice intrinsic discription. In terms of Lie groupoids, this means that $G \to M \times M$ via $s \times t$ (source and target) is a proper map of manifolds. Now, an orbifold is called effective if it is the stack of torsors for a proper etale EFFECTIVE etale Lie groupoid (I will explain below what that means). My question: Is there a way to say this in terms of properties of the stack itself without mentioning any Lie groupoids (such as having each automorphism group act effectively somewhere)? I actually care about this intrinsic characterization when $X$ is not assumed to be proper, but merely etale. I also care about the topological case.

Explanation of what effective means for Lie groupoids:

Given any space $M$, we can construct a (highly non-Hausdorff) Lie groupoid $\Gamma(M)$ out of germs of local diffeomorphims on $M$, given the arrow space the etale space topology associated to the canonical sheaf of local diffeos. Given a Lie groupoid with objects $M$, an arrow $g:x \to y$ induces a germ of a local diffeomorphism from $x$ to $y$ as follows: Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $g$ so small that the source and target maps $s$ and $t$ are diffeomorphisms on it. Then take the germ of $t \circ \left(s|_{U}\right)^{-1}$. This produces a homomorphism $G \to \Gamma(M)$. $G$ is effective if this homomorphism is injective, i.e., if every arrow is determined uniquely by its germ.

UPDATE: Actually, it would  be more helpful to know how to "naturally" extract the "effective PART" of an etale stack, without going back to the groupoid. The effective part is the image of $G$ under the canonical map to $\Gamma(G)$. This is indeed functorial at the level of stacks, but, I was hoping for a nice description of this functor in stacky language, instead of passing to a presenting groupoid. Once this is done, being effective is just the same as being equal to your effective PART. Maybe this can be done topos-theoretically, since etale stacks are equivalent to etendue.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly right, but I'll take a swing here.  The intrinsic characterisation should probably be phrased as some property of the morphism from the inertia stack $\Lambda X$ to $X$.  I think effective is equivalent to this morphism being etale, but I haven't checked it so I could easily be wrong.

Comment: I don't think that can be correct, really, though it depends on which map from the inertia stack you mean.

Consider for example $B\mathbb{Z}/2$. Then the inertia stack is just the disjoint union of two copies of this, and if the map is just the obvious projection, then this is a disconnected 2:1 cover, which is (unless I'm way off base) etale.

Comment: Properness of the diagonal means $X$ is separated, not proper.

Comment: @Laurent: For ALGEBRAIC stacks, I believe you are correct. But for topological/differentiable stacks, you want the diagonal to be a (representable) proper map, i.e., the pullback of the map along any map coming from a space becomes a proper map of spaces. (The diagonal is alway representable since it comes from a groupoid)

Comment: @Laurent: Did I misunderstand? Are you just saying the terminology of having a proper diagonal is that $X$ is called separated?

Comment: @David: Yes. Would topologists call the real line "proper" when viewed as a stack?

Comment: @Laurent: I have seen the terminology proper used, but I guess in topos theory world, the terminology separated is used. Anyhow, just to be sure we agree, yes, the real line would be proper (or separated), in fact, any Hausdorff space is (just need a proper diagonal).

Comment: @Laurent: P.S. You can see Richard Hepworth's "Vector Fields and Flows on Differentiable Stacks" for an instance where the word proper is used to describe such stacks. Anyway, there's no harm, as long as we know what we mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer this in http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.2282. An etale stack $\mathscr{X}$ is effective if and only if the substack assigning each manifold $M$ the groupoid of local diffeomorphisms $$M \to \mathscr{X}$$ is actually a sheaf, i.e. if and only if this groupoid is (equivalent to) a set.